# Php postcode validator for partial UK postcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a project that allows a user to search shops close to their postcode. As the site is now, it verifies via a full postcode only such as M28 3HE. I need to amends this to allow the user to be able to search for partial postcodes such as M28. Looking through the files, this looks to be the validator:

```
private function is_valid_postcode( $postcode ) {
    // Remove all whitespace.
    $postcode = preg_replace( '/\s/', '', $postcode );
    $postcode = strtoupper( $postcode );

    if ( preg_match( '/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2}$/', $postcode )
            || preg_match( '/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/', $postcode )
            || preg_match( '/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/', $postcode ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['shop_errors'][] = 'The postcode entered could not be validated.';
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I amend this to allow for partial postcodes?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on what exactly your definition of "partial post code" is.

Comment: On first look it should already be the case, `if ( preg_match( '/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2}$/', $postcode )` the first condition statement says: if has 1 or 2 A-Z charters and 2 numbers. Your limitation is probably coming from the HTML tag itself, the HTML <input> `min` or `max` attribute specifically. or conditioning could be enforced by javascript also. But that php function is matching what you want and should let you submit a minimum of a 3 characters string, 1 letter + 2 number.

Comment: I have amended it to:

if(preg_match("/(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?[\s]?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$)/i",$postcode)
|| preg_match("/(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]$)/i",$postcode)) {
return true;

Which now allows me to search for example SW12, but will not allow just 3 characters such as SW7. Any ideas what is wrong with the new code?